# How to moves files around based on some .csv columns?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, data-science

I have a training set folder (/train) with over ~100K images of different classes. The class of the image is given in a separate csv file that looks as follows:

```
hashed_id,country,continent,scientific_name,filename 
fd148672d8,United States of America,North America,nerodia-sipedon,fd148672d8.jpg
```

Having a folder with so many files inside, causes Colab to [timeout](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html). Hence, I would like to create a sub-folder for each scientific_name and move the images of the corresponding scientific name to it.

```
awk -F "," 'NR>1 {print $4}' train_labels.csv | head -1| xargs mkdir -p
```

This codes creates subfolders for each scientific_name if the subfolder does not exist already. It uses the comma as a separator and ignores the header.

```
cp train/$(awk -F "," 'NR>1 {print $5}' train_labels.csv | head -1) $(awk -F "," 'NR>1 {print $4}' train_labels.csv | head -1)
```

This code copies the image from the folder /train the corresponding subfolder. Note that here I am doing it here only for one image (head -1) to test it out.

I am happy I made it quite far but... is this the best way to do it? I feel there is too much repetition and I would like to have a more concise bash script.

Comment: Shouldn't `head -1` be before `xargs`? Besides, restricting the number of files in each folder seems to be a different questions. By the way, you would have to define an alternative name for those folder who would exceed 2500 files.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis you are right! It should go before. I added it and the very end for the question. I also agree with your second point... better to leave it out -> question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all with `awk` using the `system` command to create the directory and move the file. You can do it with:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{ system("mkdir -p \"" $4 "\" && mv \"" $5 "\" \""$4"\"")}' manyfiles.csv
```

The additional escaping of quotes make it look more complicated as it is. The additional quotes simply ensure your file and directory names are quoted to avoid any problems with names containing whitespace. The commands formed and used with the `system()` command are, e.g.:

```
mkdir -p "nerodia-sipedon" && mv "fd148672d8.jpg" "nerodia-sipedon"
```

If it is easier for you to understand what is going on without all the additional escaped quotes, then you would have something like the following:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{ system("mkdir -p " $4 " && mv " $5 " "$4)}' manyfiles.csv
```

(**note:** always use the quoted version)

Where the `FNR>1` simple tells `awk` to ignore the first record (no need to pipe to `head/tail` and the rest is simply a *string-concatenation* within the `system()` command to produce the command to create the directory and move the file.

This should reduce the time for moving the files considerably. (when dealing with any large number of files -- ***always keep a pristine backup*** just in case something goes awry or you want to do something else later --- "*ye have been warned...*" `:)`

Comment: Can you add to your answer how would you deal with the paths? My images are in a /train folder and I would like to create the subfolders e.g. nerodia-sipedon in /train-splits folder

Comment: I did it like this `awk -F, 'FNR>1{ system("mkdir -p train_splits/\"" $4 "\" && cp train/\"" $5 "\" train_splits/\""$4"\"")}' train_labels_short.csv` but not sure if it is the best way

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the csv file and set `IFS=,`:

```sh
while IFS=, read -r v v v type filename; do
    mkdir -p "$type"
    mv -n "$filename" "$type"
done < <(sed 1d images.csv)
```

`sed 1d file` deletes the header line from the csv file. The first three columns are red into dummy variables `v v v`.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to create the folders is good, although I would have done slightly differently:

`tail -n +2 train_labels.csv | cut -d, -f4 | sort -u | xargs mkdir -p`

I am using `tail` and `cut` to list the folders, which should be faster than `awk` for very large files. Testing with a file of 120K lines, I get around 150 ms for `awk` vs. 100 ms for `tail|cut`.

But the most import point is to sort the list with `sort -u` before feeding `mkdir` in order to minimize the number of system calls. It is true that `mkdir -p` will not create the same directory twice, but it still needs to check if the directory exists, which has a significant cost.

To copy/move the files, your solution works by simply wrapping it around a simple CSV parser using `read` with `IFS=,`

```
while IFS=, read -r hashed_id country continent scientific_name filename
do
  cp train/"$filename" "$scientific_name"/
done < train_labels.csv
```

You could group up copy/move calls for lines with the same `scientific_name`, e.g. `cp train/file1 train/file2 train/file3 my_scientific_name/` but it is a bit more complicated, it is not necessarily faster, and you might end up hitting the command line argument limit.

### Bucketing folders

If you want to fill your folders with buckets of e.g. 1000 files, you first need to define a syntax for your buckets, e.g. `$scientific_name.$index` where `$index` the your bucket. For instance, the first 1000 files of `nerodia-sipedon` will end up in `nerodia-sipedon.0` then the next 1000 files in `nerodia-sipedon.1` and so on. The naming convention is arbitrary and you may change it if you think of a better convention.

Then you may use an associative array which counts the number of times each scientific name has been used.

```
declare -A names=()
while IFS=, read -r hashed_id country continent scientific_name filename
do
  ((index=names[$scientific_name]/1000))
  ((names[$scientific_name]%1000==0)) && mkdir -p "$scientific_name"."$index"
  cp train/"$filename" "$scientific_name"."$index"/
  ((names[$scientific_name]++))
done < train_labels.csv
```

This is essentially the same algorithm as before but the `names` array stores how many times a scientific name has already been used. Moreover you don’t need to create the folders beforehand because we can check the best moment to create exactly one directory per scientific name.

Let’s break down the algorithm for the first name:

```
  ((index=names[$scientific_name]/1000))
```

Since no names have been inserted yet, `names[$scientific_name]` is equivalent to `0`, which means this line assigns `0` to `index`.

```
  ((names[$scientific_name]%1000==0)) && mkdir -p "$scientific_name"."$index"
```

Since no names have been inserted yet, `names[$scientific_name]%1000` will equal to `0` which means that the directory will be created, using the `$scientific_name.$index` syntax.

```
  cp train/"$filename" "$scientific_name"."$index"/
```

This simply copies the file to the new directory.

```
  ((names[$scientific_name]++))
```

This increments the number of entries for this scientific name. Since no names have been inserted yet, the number will be incremented from `0`, resulting in the value of `1`.

The next time an entry is found with the same scientific name, `names[$scientific_name]` will return `1`:

```
  ((index=names[$scientific_name]/1000))
```

Will assign `0` to `index`.

```
  ((names[$scientific_name]%1000==0)) && mkdir -p "$scientific_name"."$index"
```

Will *not* create the directory because the remainder of `1%1000` is not zero.

```
  cp train/"$filename" "$scientific_name"."$index"/
```

This copies the file to the existing directory.

```
  ((names[$scientific_name]++))
```

This increments the number from `1` to `2`.

This goes on like this up to the 999th entry for the same scientific name. For the 1000th entry, `index` will be `1` and a directory will be created. The 1001st file, 1002nd file, etc. will be copied to this new directory. Then the 2000th file will create another directory. Rinse and repeat.

I should mention that if you run this algorithm several times with different CSV files, your buckets may increase over the desired limit. You could solve this issue by pre-counting the number of entries for each existing directory, e.g. fill the `names` array like this:

```
declare -A names=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' folder
do
  scientific_name=${folder%.*}
  (( names[$scientific_name]+=$(find "$folder" -type f | wc -l) ))
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '?*.?*' -printf '%f\0')
```